# WebApi 2 using entity Framework Retrieving

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-web-api

What I want to achieve is that to retrieve all data from the database, as of now I know that I need to replace

> SingleOrDefault

with something else and can I know what is the method below called ? I don’t think is linq ?

```
[Route("api/{AuthCode}/LoadWorkers")]
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GET(String Authcode)
{
    DateTime futureDate = new DateTime();
    futureDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90);
    worker result = new worker();
    result = KKDB.workers.SingleOrDefault(p => p.WWPED <= futureDate);
    return Task.FromResult(Request.CreateResponse<worker>(HttpStatusCode.OK, result));
}
```

Solution

```
[Route("api/{AuthCode}/LoadWorkers")]
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GET(String Authcode)
{
  DateTime futureDate = new DateTime();
  futureDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90);
  var result = KKDB.workers.Where(x => x.WWPED <= futureDate);
  return Task.FromResult(Request.CreateResponse<IQueryable<worker>>HttpStatusCode.OK,result));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.Where(x => x.WWPED <= futureDate)` that will get you the entities, you can then map them into the desired format for returning as result.  This might be easier using linq.